# Need an updated Twitter stream nodejs api

Tags: node.js, api, twitter, stream

can you help me with a better updated twitter stream api in nodejs? Currently I am trying out the ntwitter API but its pretty old and some of its methods aren't working. So please suggest a good streaming api for twitter in nodejs.

Comment: Have you checked `Twit API` ?

Comment: hey thanks I'll take a look...is it upto date?

Comment: yes its upto date with some good examples doc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Kindly check below `Twitter API Client for node`:-

- [`Twit API`](https://github.com/ttezel/twit) `//Supports both the REST and Streaming API.`

Comment: does it also handle the reconnection strategy?

Comment: @Abhidev event: 'reconnect'emitted when a reconnection attempt to Twitter is scheduled. If Twitter is having problems or rate limited, it reconnects according to [Twitter's reconnection guidelines](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/streaming-apis/connecting)

Comment: Of the myriad of Twitter clients for Node, easily the best I've come across; out of the box Streaming and REST support. Thanks!